# Disable dynamically a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I use the [jquery numeric plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric) to allow only numbers to be typed in some fields.

```
$("input.numeric").numeric();
```

I want to disable this function dynamically in some cases, to allow the user to type others characters (i.e. letters).
I tryed to use the unbind() or undelegate() functions without success.

Does anyone know the solution ?
Thanks

Comment: How did you use `.unbind()`? The numeric plugin just seems to bind a `keypress` handler to the input, so `$("input.numeric").unbind();` should remove that (and every other) handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finaly, I found this solution :
$('#my_elt').unbind('keypress').unbind('blur');
I unbind all events used by the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

This plugin contains function `removeNumeric();`

And It's almost correct.
At first you should add a little fix in jquer.numeric plugin:

insert `unbind("keyup", $.fn.numeric.keyup)` at `removeNumeric` function

```
$.fn.removeNumeric = function()
{
  return this.data("numeric.decimal", null).data("numeric.negative",
  null).data("numeric.callback", null).unbind("keypress",
  $.fn.numeric.keypress).*unbind("keyup",
  $.fn.numeric.keyup)*.unbind("blur", $.fn.numeric.blur);
}
```

Well, and after that, you could try `$("input.numeric").removeNumeric();`
Works fine for me.